# How to import a collection of .ics files using lotusscript

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a collection of .ics files which I need to import into Notes calendars.  I'm not seeing anything in the Notes Designer help about it but could have missed it.  Did some searching too.  There are a number of code snipets about how to generate a .ics file but did not see anything about importing them via LotusScript.  Any ideas?

thanks
clem

Comment: Can I presume that emailing them to users to import through the black magic of the Notes client is out of the question?

Comment: Correct.  They are being created from a different application and dumped into a folder.  I was asked if it would be possible have and agent import them from the folder.